# Why do the scripts and comments appear during execution?

Tags: makefile

In my makefile, I have a target called `indent-fast` --

```
indent-fast:
    # astyle --style=allman --indent=tab `find . -name "*.java"`
    files=`find . -name "*.java"` ; \
    for file in $$files ; do \
        echo formatting $$file ; \
    done ;\
    # to do a whitesmith at 4 spaces, uncomment this line --
    # astyle --style=whitesmith --indent=spaces=4 `find . -name "*.java"`
```

but when I execute it, I get this output --

```
ramgorur@ramgorur-pc:~$ make indent-fast

# astyle --style=allman --indent=tab `find . -name "*.java"`
files=`find . -name "*.java"` ; \
    for file in $files ; do \
        echo formatting $file ; \
    done ;\
formatting ./File1.java
formatting ./File2.java
formatting ./File3.java
.
.
.
formatting ./FileN.java
# to do a whitesmith at 4 spaces, uncomment this line --
# astyle --style=whitesmith --indent=spaces=4 `find . -name "*.java"`
```

why is it showing the scripts along with the comments on the std output? Please also note that `indent-fast` is the last target in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your comments are indented in a recipe, they're not `make` comments, and they're being executed as part of the recipe.  They're shell comments in that context.  You could add an `@` to prevent them from being output, if that's your goal.

From the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):

> Comments within a recipe are passed to the shell, just as with any other recipe text. The shell decides how to interpret it: whether or not this is a comment is up to the shell.

Simple example makefile:

```
# make comment
target:
    # shell comment
    :
    @# output-suppressed shell comment
    @:
```

Execution:

```
$ make
# shell comment
:
```

Edit: since an example wasn't good enough, here's the solution for your exact problem:

```
indent-fast:
    @# astyle --style=allman --indent=tab `find . -name "*.java"`
    @files=`find . -name "*.java"` ; \
    for file in $$files ; do \
        echo formatting $$file ; \
    done
    @# to do a whitesmith at 4 spaces, uncomment this line --
    @# astyle --style=whitesmith --indent=spaces=4 `find . -name "*.java"`
```

Comment: well, thanks I can suppress comments with `@`, but it still shows the `for` loop body and also throws this error `/bin/sh: 5: @#: not found make: *** [indent-fast] Error 127`

Comment: If you don't want the `for` loop body, put an `@` in front of the command that it includes.  The reason you get the error is you put an `@` in the wrong spot and the shell is trying to interpret it.

Comment: Just to add: if you don't want them printed, then don't indent them with a TAB.  If it's not indented with a TAB, then it's not part of the recipe, it's a `make` comment, and make won't pass it to the shell.

Comment: @MadScientist, that works for the comments, but not for the loop.  In this case, the comments are clearly intended to be part of the recipe, so it's not that unreasonable to do it this way.